# How to achieve parallelism in C?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pthreads, fork

This might be a dumb question, i'm very sorry if that's the case. But i'm struggling to take advantage of the multiple cores in my computer to perform multiple computations at the same time in my Quad-Core MacBook. This is not for any particular project, just a general question, since i want to learn for when i eventually do need to do this kind of things

I am aware of threads, but the seem to run in the same core, so i don't seem to gain any performance using them for compute-bound operations (They are very useful for socket based stuff tho!).

I'm also aware of processed that can be created with fork, but i'm nor sure they are guaranteed to use more CPU, or if they, like threads, just help with IO-bound operations.

Finally i'm aware of CUDA, allowing paralellism in the GPU (And i think OpenCL and Compute Shaders also allows my code to run in the CPU in parallel) but i'm currently looking for something that will allow me to take advantage of the multiple CPU cores that my computer has.

In python, i'm aware of the multiprocessing module, which seems to provide an API very similar to threads, but there i do seem to gain an edge by running multiple functions performing computations in parallel. I'm looking into how could i get this same advantage in C, but i don't seem to be able

Any help pointing me to the right direction would be very much appreciated

Note: I'm trying to achive true parallelism, not concurrency

Note 2: I'm only aware of threads and using multiple processes in C, with threads i don't seem to be able to win the performance boost i want. And i'm not very familiar with processes, but i'm still not sure if running multiple processes is guaranteed to give me the advantage i'm looking for.

Comment: _"threads, but the seem to run in the same core"_ - why do you think that? You've clearly made mistakes trying to use them, but we can't tell you what those mistakes are unless you show a [mre].

Comment: @TedLyngmo The monitoring of my CPU usage and my performance metrics seems to indicate the process, while concurrent, never overlap. Are they expected to overlap? Maybe my environment is the problem here, not the code

Comment: Properly used you should be able to reach close to 100% utilization on all cores simultaneously (if you have a task that can be split up in that many sub tasks).

Comment: Yes, that kinda what i was expecting to be able to do, and is i said, i could manage to do that in python, processing a few file and gaining a considerable perfomance advantage, that's why not being able to do so in C has stumped me. But i look into it! The pure confirmation that threads SHOULD be working in parallel but they are not doing so points me greatly in the right direction, thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem! Yeah, sometimes confirmation that one is on the right track is all it takes to not give up :-)

Comment: Maybe turn your comments into an answer so that i can mark it as correct!

Comment: Well, I think I'll leave them as comments for now. If you do add a small example (a [mre]) to your question I may pick it up and suggest what needs to be done in an answer (if I can figure it out that is).

Comment: Threads and processes differ in a few ways, but amount of possible concurrency is not one of them (except on systems with green/user threads, which yours is not). If you have several threads and only one seems to run at a time, it's probably because they're competing for a shared resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple program to heat up your CPU (100% utilization of all available cores).

**Hint:** The thread starting function does not return, program exit via [CTRL + C]

```
#include <pthread.h>

void* func(void *arg)
{
    while (1);
}

int main()
{
    #define NUM_THREADS 4 //use the number of cores (if known)
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

    for (int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, func, NULL);

    for (int i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
gcc -pthread -o thread_test thread_test.c
```

If i start `./thread_test`, all cores are at 100%.

---

A word to `fork` and `pthread_create`:

`fork` creates a new process (the current process image will be copied and executed in parallel), while `pthread_create` will create a new thread, sometimes called a lightweight process.

Both, processes and threads will run in 'parallel' to the parent process.

It depends, when to use a child process over a thread, e.g. a child is able to replace its process image (via `exec` family) and has its own address space, while threads are able to share the address space of the current parent process.

There are of course a lot more differences, for that i recommend to study the following pages:

- [man fork](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)
- [man pthreads](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)

Comment: Yup, this seems to be working in my machine now, thanks a lot! I get 390% CPU usage acording to my mac's activity monitor, meaning that things are indeed working very much in parallel now! I'm not really sure what was not working before since my code wasn't too different, but it's working now, so i now know what to look into!

Comment: As the user @Useless stated in the comments above: _it's probably because they're competing for a shared resource_

Comment: Please note that technically `while (1);` causes an undefined behaviour as it does not have any visible impact ;) (so compiler can and can sometimes remove it). A big loop on a thread-local volatile value should do the job. Note that C11 now provide a portable API. Btw, one should not forget to use optimizations (`-O2` or `-O3`) for real-world applications though this is fine for this example.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you for your additional Information. You're right, but my example is not a real world program, just for illustration purposes. First i wanted to implement a big loop but `while(1);` came so fast into mind, that i even did not dare to write `for(;;);`, yet a longer statement :)

Comment: @JérômeRichard, that `while(1);` has no *observable* behavior does not mean that it has *undefined* behavior.  The former is sufficient to allow the compiler to optimize the loop to some kind of non-busy indefinite wait, but probably not to optimize it out completely.  The latter, on the other hand, would allow the compiler to replace the loop with nothing, or a call to `exit()` or `raise()`, or anything at all else.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, `while(1);` will probably be eliminated by the compiler optimizer if you don't do anything with it.  Your thread can be turned into a `pause(2)` call, to avoid consuming cpu.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No, this is clearly an undefined behaviour. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub): "*Endless loop with no side effects is UB*". Moreover, [Clang optimizes this out](https://godbolt.org/z/jTE738vTs).

Comment: @LuisColorado I know for the optimization as I stated this in my comment. This is still an UB though and compiler can do whatever they want in this case (and sometimes they do since optimizers can make crazy assumptions in this case...). In the above example, Clang decides to remove not only the loop but also the following code. Regarding the pause, the purpose of the example was to show multiple cores are used, so a passive waiting function is not great for that.

Comment: @LuisColorado Why are you talking about `fork`? I answered to your comment about the `while(1);` and `pause`. Nothing about `fork` here. I am confused.

Comment: I'm confused too.  My apologies as I answer more than one question per day and I was in other context.

Answer (score 0):

> I am aware of threads, but the seem to run in the same core, so i don't seem to gain any performance using them for compute-bound operations (They are very useful for socket based stuff tho!).

No, they don't.  Except if you block and your threads don't block, you'll see alll of them running.  Just try this (beware that this consumes all your cpu time) that starts 16 threads each counting in a busy loop for 60 s.  You will see all of them running and makins your cores to fail to their knees (it runs only a minute this way, then everything ends):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 16 /* had 16 cores, so I used this. Put here as many
              * threads as cores you have. */

struct thread_data {
    pthread_t       thread_id; /* the thread id */
    struct timespec end_time;  /* time to get out of the tunnel */
    int             id;        /* the array position of the thread */
    unsigned long   result;    /* number of times looped */
};

void *thread_body(void *data)
{
    struct thread_data *p = data;
    p->result = 0UL;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &p->end_time);
    p->end_time.tv_sec += 60; /* 60 s. */
    struct timespec now;
    do {
        /* just get the time */
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
        p->result++;
        /* if you call printf() you will see them slowing, as there's a
         * common buffer that forces all thread to serialize their outputs
         */
      /* check if we are over */
    } while (  now.tv_sec  < p->end_time.tv_sec
            || now.tv_nsec < p->end_time.tv_nsec);
    return p;
} /* thread_body */


int main()
{
    struct thread_data thrd_info[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        struct thread_data *d = &thrd_info[i];

        d->id = i;
        d->result = 0;

        printf("Starting thread %d\n", d->id);
        int res = pthread_create(&d->thread_id,
                NULL, thread_body, d);
        if (res < 0) {
            perror("pthread_create");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Thread %d started\n", d->id);
    }

    printf("All threads created, waiting for all to finish\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        struct thread_data *joined;
        int res = pthread_join(thrd_info[i].thread_id,
                (void **)&joined);
        if (res < 0) {
            perror("pthread_join");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("PTHREAD %d ended, with value %lu\n",
                joined->id, joined->result);
    }
} /* main */
```

Linux and all multithread systems work the same, they create a new execution unit (if both don't share the virtual address space, they are both processes --not exactly so, but this explains the main difference between a process and a thread--) and the available processors are given to each thread as necessary.  Threads are normally encapsulated inside processes (they share ---not in linux, if that has not changed recently--- the process id, and virtual memory)  Processes run each in a separate virtual space, so they can only share things through the system resources (files, shared memory, communication sockets/pipes, etc.)

The problem with your test case (you don't show it so I have go guess) is that probably you will make all threads in a loop in which you try to print something.  If you do that, probably the most time each thread is blocked trying to do I/O (to `printf()` something)

Stdio `FILE`s have the problem that they share a buffer between all threads that want to print on the same `FILE`, and the kernel serializes all the `write(2)` system calls to the same file descriptor, so if the most of the time you pass in the loop is blocked in a write, the kernel (and stdio) will end serializing all the calls to print, making it to appear that only one thread is working at a time (all the threads will become blocked by the one that is doing the I/O)  This busy loop will make all the threads to run in parallel and will show you how the cpu is collapsed.

Answer (score -3):

Parallelism in C can be achieved by using the fork() function. This function simulates a thread by allowing two threads to run simultaneously and share data. The first thread forks itself, and the second thread is then executed as if it was launched from main(). Forking allows multiple processes to be Run concurrently without conflicts arising.
To make sure that data is shared appropriately between the two threads, use the wait() function before accessing shared resources. Wait will block execution of the current program until all database connections are closed or all I/O has been completed, whichever comes first.

Comment: _"Parallelism in C can be achieved by using the fork() function. This function simulates a thread by allowing two threads to run simultaneously and share data."_ - You've misunderstood what `fork()` actually does.

Comment: Please read the man/doc: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html . The *first line* mention processes, not threads. Besides, `fork` is not a portable function. It targets POSIX systems so it does not work on Windows. Thread should generally be used instead of processes if possible. C11 provide a portable threading API.

Comment: `fork()` creates another process, you cannot share data with your parent and so, all your answer is wrong.  Using threads is the way.  Sorry for the downvote.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, are you trully telling that `fork()` is nonportable???? Where did you get that?  Can you, please, elaborate?

Comment: @LuisColorado As mentioned, `fork` is a POSIX function. Thus, it does not work on non POSIX compliant systems like Windows. Windows uses another mechanism to create processes (using `CreateProcess` which do not fork the process but creates a new one).

Comment: yes.  You are right.  There are systems that don't have it.  But the first C compiler had support for it, in the original Unix System.  Almost every system has an emulation of fork().  But you are right.... some systems don't have it.